# TypeError: default is not a function when using vitest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vitest

I'm using vitest to do some unit tests in my vue application.
I've written some tests but they fail with the error message: 'TypeError: default is not a function'.
But I do not use a function called default() in my code.

```
import getInfo from './info';

vi.mock('axios', () => {
    return {
        default: {
            get: vi.fn()
        }
    }
});

test('fn getInfo() should request api with axios.get url', async () => {
    const spyAxios = vi.spyOn(axios, 'get');
    await getInfo('1234');
    expect(spyAxios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL}`);
});
```

If I then execute `npm run test` the result is the following:

```
 FAIL  src/api/info/info.test.js > fn getInfo() should request api with axios.get url
TypeError: default is not a function
 ❯ src/api/info/info.test.js:61:22
     59| test('fn getInfo() should request api with axios.get url', async () => {
     60|     const spyAxios = vi.spyOn(axios, 'get');
     61|     await getInfo('1234');
       |                  ^
     62|     expect(spyAxios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL}`);
     63| });
```

The info.ts file looks like the following:

```
import { useLoginStore } from "../../store/LoginStore";
import axios from "axios";

// eslint-disable-next-line
export async function getInfo(param: string) : Promise<any> {
    const loginStore = useLoginStore();
    axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${loginStore.accessToken}`};
    
    const request = await axios.get(
        process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL
    );

    if (request?.status == 200) {
        return request.data;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Please share the `info` file

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've added the info.ts file to the original question.

Comment: Ref: *"But I do not use a function called default() in my code."*: `import axios from "axios"` is actually importing axios module's *"default"* export. What's not clear to me is why and where is that export used as a function, because it shouldn't be. Look for any place where you're calling `axios` as a function, especially around current test.

Comment: I use `axios.get()` in info.ts file and `vi.spyOn(axios)` in info.test.js.

Comment: Additional information: 
If I execute `vitest --ui` and navigate in the UI to 'Module Graph' and select info.test.js I can see the original code (written by me) and the transformed code of that file which was created by vitest.
There I can see the following code line:
`await __vite_ssr_import_1__.default('1234');`

For me it looks like vitest transforms the code from `await getInfo('1234');` to `await __vite_ssr_import_1__.default('1234');` 

Could this `default()` method be the problem?

Comment: I have executed the test in debug mode and found out that the error is actually in the auto-generated file in line `await __vite_ssr_import_1__.default('1234');`.

Answer (score 3):

The `default` attribute in your return object is not a function (`default: {...}`).  Instead, you would return something like this:

```
vi.mock('axios', () => ({
  default: () => ({
    get: vi.fn(),
    post: vi.fn(),
  }),
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your test, instead of this:

```
import getInfo from './info';
```

Do this:

```
import { getInfo } from './info';
```

**Problem**

Your test is importing `getInfo` as default from `info.ts`. But in your `info.ts` you're not exporting `getInfo` as default. As such, you should import the function as a **named import**, putting it in curly braces, not as a **default import** as you currently have.